# how to import objective-c++ file

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm having trouble including a .mm file in my cocoa project. The .mm file #includes the .cpp file. If I don't #import the project builds fine. However, I need to #import the .mm file but when I do, I get 'string' file not found. How do I use the mm file without getting that error?

[Here is a link to the project](https://github.com/saltzmanjoelh/ObjCPPTest/tree/master/ObjCPPTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use #import with a .mm file.  Move its public interface into a .h file and import **that** where you need it.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. The wrapper's header file has to import the cpp file to know about the class type for the ivar...

Comment: @joels Try using forward declarations in the header file. `@class ClassNameThatsNeeded;` for Objective-C classes, and `class ClassNameThatsNeeded;` for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to move the part of the interface that defines the cpp ivar to the implementation file
CPPWrapper.mm

```
@interface CPPWrapper ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) Cpp *cpp;
@end

@implementation CPPWrapper
@synthesize cpp = _cpp;
//do stuff with cpp ivar here
@end
```

Comment: Like I said, move the **public** interface.  :-)

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense now. I took it as move ALL the interface to header file